# Async CTP on Windows Phone - cannot using offline?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-ctp

I have this WP7 application for reading web feeds. I'm using Async CTP for downloading feeds, save them locally and use them, so I would be able to use App offline.

Everything works great when I'm connected to wifi or cellular. But when I'm offline, Application crash on starting with error:

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Call stack location:

> AsyncCTPLibrary_Phone.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBulder.SetException.AnonymousMethod_2(object
>   state)

StackTrace:

> at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_8(Object
>   state2)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)    at
>   System.Threading.Timer.ring()

Any idea why? I'm not automatically downlodading anything...

**Edit:** Here's starting part of code, I realy try to avoid calling web client if I'm offline:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     MainPage_Init();
 }


private async void MainPage_Init()
 {
     string isConfig = await Load_Config("");

         if (isLoaded == false)
         {
        if (RSS.Parameters.AutoUpdate == "On")
                {
                    string isDataOk = await Refresh_data(); 
                    Refresh_ui();
                }
            else
                {
                    Refresh_ui();
                }
        isLoaded = true;
         }
 }

async Task<string> Load_Config(string force)
 {
     if (!DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(RSS.Parameters.MessageNetwork);
         //Load Config from IsoStore
         return "No Network";
     }
     else
     {
         string data = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
         return await GetConfig_Save_Local_XML_Async(data);
         //Load Config from Web, Save to IsoStore
     }
 }

private async Task<string> Refresh_data() //load feeds form Internet and save them to IsoStore
 {
     IsolatedStorageSettings isoStorage = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

     if (!DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
     {
         ProgressBarSwitch("off");
         MessageBox.Show(RSS.Parameters.MessageNetwork);

     }
     else
     {
         foreach (RSSFeedInfo sfi in RSS.Parameters.FeedsInfo)
         {
        await Load_Web_XML(new Uri(sfi.Web_XML), sfi.Local_XML);
         }
         isoStorage["SettingsLastUpdate"] = System.DateTime.Now;
         isoStorage.Save();
         ProgressBarSwitch("off");
     }
     return "ok";
 }

private void Refresh_ui() //load feeds from IsoStore
 {
     //use local data
 }
```

Comment: You will need to show us parts of code where you're using Async.

Comment: I added start code to post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *always* have a `try`/`catch` around network code. There are a lot of possible error conditions, of which being offline is only one.

For example, if you're connected to a local WiFi without Internet, `IsNetworkAvailable` will return `true`, even though there's no Internet access.

Comment: you are absolutely right :) i added try/catch around this and problem dissapears.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202859%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), `IsNetworkAvailable` can return `true` even when none of the underlying services are connected:

So some code like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("Network available:  ");
  sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable.ToString());
  sb.Append("Cellular enabled:  ");
  sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled.ToString());
  sb.Append("Roaming enabled:  ");
  sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled.ToString());
  sb.Append("Wi-Fi enabled:  ");
  sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled.ToString());
  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());}
```

Could provide you with output along the lines of:

- Network available: True
- Cellular enabled: False
- Roaming enabled: False
- Wi-Fi enabled: False